# Eclipse vs VS IDE Unit Testing a class

Tags: visual-studio-2008, eclipse, testing

In Eclipse you can right click on a class (even if it is a web project) that has a main method and run or debug it.  It facilitates for quick testing.  In Visual Studio when you want to run a specific class, how do you do it, without having to change the start up class etc..?

Answer (score 1):

Your title asks about unit testing, which I view as different from running a `Main` method. For unit testing, I'd recommend [ReSharper](http://jetbrains.com/resharper) which lets you run individual tests, whole classes, whole namespace hierarchies, and whole assemblies (in terms of unit tests).

I don't typically write `Main` methods for unit tests. Where I *do* write multiple `Main` methods is for demoing code in talks - and for that, I've got a little helper in [MiscUtil](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/miscutil) so that you can create *one* main method which calls into MiscUtil, and that presents a menu showing all the other static `Main` methods in the assembly. Have a look at the [downloadable source code for C# in Depth](http://csharpindepth.com/Downloads.aspx) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

I've used NUnit very successfully for exactly this sort of purpose.  In general, writing a unit test in NUnit is quicker, simpler, and easier than writing a main() method on a class.  Really, any Unit Test framework would fit this requirement; I've just used (and been very happy with) NUnit.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a plugin for VS called [testdriven.net](http://www.testdriven.net/) that I have used in the past, which will more or less let you plug in your test framework of choice and run your tests from VS.  It supports NUnit and MBUnit, I believe neither of which require a Main method.  You just decorate classes as test fixtures and the framework can handle them independently.